# Qt Object instantiation query

Tags: c++, qt, object, qt4

```
QObject *obj;
...
if ( /* obj is already instantiated */ ) {
    ;
} else {
    obj = new QObject();
}
```

My query is the condition of the **if**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1) Initialize your object pointer to NULL

2) Check for NULL in your `if` statement

```
QObject *obj = NULL;
...
if ( obj != NULL ) {
    ;
} else {
    obj = new QObject();
}
```

Comment: Actually, NULL is a C-ism. For a modern compiler, please use nullptr instead.

Comment: I guess Qt discarded NULL. And ask to use 0 in stead. But **ISO forbids initialization of members** like error I get when using **QObject *obj = 0;**

Comment: If `obj` is a member variable, then it should be initialized to 0/NULL/nullptr (take your pick) inside of your class's constructor, preferably in the initializer list.

Answer (score 0):

```
QObject *obj = 0;

// ...

if (!obj) obj = new QObject();
```

---

*Note: Makes no guarantee `obj` is not a [dangling pointer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dangling_pointer).*

Answer (score 0):

Use `QPointer` class. http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qpointer.html#data

Whenever you call `deleteLater();` it will set it to 0, than you can check it.

`QPointer<QWidget> someWidget = 0;`